# Removing Quotes From Tuple in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, tuples

I have the following code

```
for files in self.dbCur.execute('SELECT pagename FROM pagelayout'):
    files = list(files)
    self.webgrid.insert(END, files)
```

This produces the following

```
["test 2"]
["test 3"]
```

I need it to produce this:

```
test 2
test 3
```

How can I do that. I have looked for the answer and just can't seem to find. 
Thanks.

Comment: `test 2` is a string and it would be represented as `"test 2"`

Comment: Okay. But I need to put the value test 2 into a listbox without the quotes. I read one value from the database, which is test 2, then I put the value into a tkinter listbox, but it also adds the brackets and quotes.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified my problem better.

Comment: What type of widget is `webgrid`? Is it a listbox?

Comment: Yes, it's a list box

Answer (score -3):

You just need to print the elements of the list instead of printing the entire list.

```
for item in self.webgrid:
    print item
```

Comment: I get an error when using this about converting a str to int implicitly.

Comment: "Test 1" does not convert to an int. Separate problem.